# How does std::weak_ptr store its "use_count" information?

Tags: c++, count, reference, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

I tried to understand the principle behind weak_ptr's implementation, especially about ref-counting.

The cppreference https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr says weak_ptr works as an observer of shared_ptr, declaring weak_ptr doesn't change the use_count of original shared_ptr. Then my question is, how is weak_ptr implemented to know the use_count of original shared_ptr. I guess weak_ptr will hold a integer pointer to shared_ptr's use_count.

I had a quick test:

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    auto sp = make_shared<int>(10);
    weak_ptr<int> wp(sp);
    cout << wp.use_count() << endl; // 1
    sp.reset(new int{5});
    cout << wp.use_count() << endl; // 0
    auto swp = wp.lock();
    cout << swp.get() << endl; // 0
    cout << *swp << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

As you could see the result of my program, as comments. So

(1) If weak_ptr doesn't hold an integer pointer to shared_ptr's use_count, then , how does it know the use_count() should change from 1 to 0 when I called `sp.reset(new int[5])`. How could it know?

(2) If it holds such a pointer, when original shared_ptr came to end of lifecycle and destroyed, this pointer will point to a non-exist position! Dangling pointer!

Thus it seems to me a contradictory about how to implement weak_ptr.

Would you give some hints? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` have an internal *control block* which contains internal meta-data, like for example the use counter. This control block is shared with the weak pointer.

Comment: Check https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr#Implementation_notes for details about the *control block*

Comment: "weak_ptr doesn't **change** the use_count of original shared_ptr" is no contradiction to weak_ptr storing a pointer to the shared_ptrs use count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to understand the principle behind weak_ptr's **implementation**

Take one implementation and observe it. For example on libstdc++ the class `__weak_ptr` contains https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/shared_ptr_base.h#L1974 the pointer to memory and the counter:

```
template<typename _Tp, _Lock_policy _Lp>
    class __weak_ptr {
    ...

       _Tp*               _M_ptr;         // Contained pointer.
      __weak_count<_Lp>  _M_refcount;    // Reference counter.
    };
```

Where `__weak_count` contains a **pointer** to the counter:

```
 template<_Lock_policy _Lp>
    class __weak_count
    {
      ...
      _Sp_counted_base<_Lp>*  _M_pi;
    };
```

Where `_Sp_counted_base` actually holds the counters:

```
  template<_Lock_policy _Lp = __default_lock_policy>
    class _Sp_counted_base
    : public _Mutex_base<_Lp>
    {
      ....
      _Atomic_word  _M_use_count;     // #shared
      _Atomic_word  _M_weak_count;    // #weak + (#shared != 0)
    };
```

> If it holds such a pointer, when original shared_ptr came to end of lifecycle and destroyed, this pointer will point to a non-exist position!

Not if the count itself is dynamically allocated! From https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/shared_ptr_base.h#L913 `__shared_count` allocates `_Sp_counted_ptr` on construction dynamically:

```
template<_Lock_policy _Lp>
class __shared_count
{
   ...
      template<typename _Ptr>
        explicit
    __shared_count(_Ptr __p) : _M_pi(0)
    {
       ...
          _M_pi = new _Sp_counted_ptr<_Ptr, _Lp>(__p);
       ...
    }
  ...
  _Sp_counted_base<_Lp>*  _M_pi;
};
```

Where `_Sp_counted_ptr` is dynamically allocated, and it holds the pointer to memory *and the counters* by inheriting from `_Sp_counted_base`:

```
  template<typename _Ptr, _Lock_policy _Lp>
      // _Sp_counted_base has the count
    class _Sp_counted_ptr final : public _Sp_counted_base<_Lp>
    {

    private:
      _Ptr             _M_ptr;  // the pointer to memory
    };
```